# The Proper Way to Setup Static Roots Django Dreamhost

Tags: python, django, static, hosting, django-urls

I've tried dozens of ways to find the most useful way to serve static files on my hosting with dreamhost. **So far only one way has worked for me and that is to make the `STATIC_URL` a hyper-link.** This might work however becomes somewhat a dynamic hindrance in particularly when collecting my static files. I'm using passenger_wsgi to host my website. Everything else is working correctly except for the way static files are served. **How can I serve my static files most effectively?** Please include where I should put my static files, the `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT`, and `urlpatterns` in the answer. Python 2.7 Django 1.9

My Current Site Structure:

```
home/user/domain.com/
     /env
     /MyDjangoProject
     /tmp
         restart.txt
     /public
          /static_in_pub
               /static_root
                    /css
                    /js
               /media
     passenger.wsgi.py
```

My settings.py Static Roots:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://www.domain.com/static_in_pub/static_root/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static_in_env/static_root')

MEDIA_URL = 'http://www.domain.com/static_in_pub/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static_in_env/media')

print 'Settings.py STATIC_ROOT: %s' % (STATIC_ROOT)
print 'Settings.py MEDIA_ROOT: %s' % (MEDIA_ROOT)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_in_pro/our_static'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_in_pro/media'),
    #'/var/www/static/',
)
```

My static urlpatterns in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "make the STATIC_URL a hyper-link"?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = 'http://www.domain.com/static_in_pub/static_root/'` is a hyperlink, instead of going with the full path directory `STATIC_URL = '/home/user/domain.com/public/static_in_pub/our_static/'` which didn't work for me, or just `/static/` which also did not work.

Comment: Example, currently my css files are accessible like: `http://www.domain.com/static_in_pub/static_root/css/home.css` I want them accessible like this: `http://www.domain.com/static/home.css`

Comment: No, that's nonsense. '/home/user/whatever' is a directory path, not a URL. You couldn't - and wouldn't want to - use it as the URL to access your files; his would the browser know what to do with it?

Comment: Well my current way makes STATIC_ROOT useless or pointless because STATIC_URL displays the css files directly.

Comment: Yes that is what is supposed to happen. You configure Dreamhost to serve files directly.

Comment: So I set this up correctly then? What is the point of STATIC_ROOT then? Isn't STATIC_ROOT supposed to serve the files with the STATIC_URL?

Comment: No, the documentation is absolutely cheat that Django does not serve static files. STATIC_ROOT is where files are placed by the collectstatic command.

Comment: On localhost I was able to use STATIC_URL = "/static/" and the files would be served as http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ but this doesn't seem to work under apache hosting.

Comment: Yes. The documentation says that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel-Roseman's answer is correct. You are supposed to serve the static files directly like I have in my question. With Apache files are served with a direct link: `STATIC_URL = 'http://www.domain.com/static_in_env/static_root'` However from my own experience I find it better to keep the static files in the directory above public and serve them from there.

Like this:

```
home/user/domain.com/
     /env
     /MyDjangoProject
     /tmp
         restart.txt
          /static_in_env #Static in here instead of in public
               /static_root
     /public
     passenger.wsgi.py
```